# Workspace.Gromaniak85.LocalScript:7: Expected ')' (to close '(' at column 25), got '.2xblock'

Tags: lua, roblox

what I'm trying to do is to get the distance from chracters torso to the block. I don't know why, but when im referencing the folder, it gives that error.

this is the error code:
Workspace.Gromaniak85.LocalScript:7: Expected ')' (to close '(' at column 25), got '.2xblock'

```
local DistanceRemote = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").DistanceFromBlock
local player = script.Parent.Parent
local BrickMultipliers = game.Workspace.BrickMultipliers

while true do
    wait(0.5)
    local distancefrom2x = (game.Workspace[player.Name].UpperTorso.Position - BrickMultipliers.2xblock.Position).magnitude --error happens there
    print(distancefrom2x)
end
```

Here it's how it is in studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTMar.png

I don't really know what to do, so I'll be thankfull for all help !!

Comment: A field name can not start with a digit.  Rename it to something else.

Comment: Or access it as `BrickMultipliers["2xblock"].Position`

Comment: Please prefer code not image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Lua's lexical conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1) a name may not begin with a digit!

> Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of Latin
> letters, Arabic-Indic digits, and underscores, **not beginning with a
> digit** and not being a reserved word. Identifiers are used to name
> variables, table fields, and labels.
>
> The following keywords are reserved and cannot be used as names:
>
> ```
>  and       break     do        else      elseif    end
>  false     for       function  goto      if        in
>  local     nil       not       or        repeat    return
>  then      true      until     while
> ```

Hence this is invalid syntax: `BrickMultipliers.2xblock.Position`

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 3.2 - Variables:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.2)

> The syntax var.Name is just syntactic sugar for var["Name"]:
>
> var ::= prefixexp ‘.’ Name

So this convenient syntax only works for Lua identifiers (names).

As `2xblock` begins with a digit so it cannot be a name. Thus `BrickMultipliers.2xblock` causes an error.

For any table key that is not a Lua name you have to use the square bracket notation.

`BrickMultipliers["2xblock"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference objects in Lua that start with symbols (numbers included). You would have to wrap it in square brackets and quotation marks. This means that you would also take away the dot (.): `BrickMultipliers["2xblock"].Position` This combines the integer (the 2) with the rest of the string (xblock), allowing for Roblox to be able to successfully reference your part.

Comment: `tostring` does not combine integers with strings. while your solution is correct your reasoning is quite naive, misleading and wrong.